# D3.js Time scale starting at now

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a graph which shows live data over the past 90 minutes currently my x axis is labelled 90 to 0 using

```
xRRange = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right])
                           .domain([90,0])
```

What I want to do is replace the numbers 0 - 90 with times, ie the 90 would be now-90 and the 0 would be now
I have tried the following but it fails to draw the axis, any ideas where I have went wrong

```
var xStart = Math.round(+new Date()/1000);
var xEnd = xStart - (60*90);
xTRange = d3.scale.time().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right])
                         .domain([xEnd, xStart])
                         .nice() 
xTAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xTRange)
                      .tickSize(20)
                      .tickSubdivide(true);
vis.append('svg:g').attr('class', 'x axis')
                   .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ')')
                   .call(xTAxis);
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have swapped the xEnd and xStart. In your first code block, the smaller value is at the end. In your 2nd, the larger values is at the end.

Also, your first line converts the xStart and xEnd values into seconds. You don't convert them back to milliseconds in your `domain` call. When d3 coerces them into dates, they won't be what you expect (will be far lesser)

Answer (score 0):

As @potatopeelings excellent answer states, JavaScript works with milliseconds.  Also, a couple of other things. It's `d3.time.scale`, not `d3.scale.time`.  And in your scale assignment, you need to reverse your `xEnd` and `xStart`.

Here it all is working:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var vis = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 400)
      .attr('height', 150);

    var xStart = new Date();
    var xEnd = xStart - (90 * 60000); // 60,000 milliseconds in minute

    xTRange = d3.time.scale()
      .range([20, 380])
      .domain([xStart, xEnd])
      .nice();

    xTAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xTRange)
      .tickSize(20)
      .tickSubdivide(true);
      
    vis.append('svg:g').attr('class', 'x axis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + 10 + ')')
      .call(xTAxis);
      
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I had misunderstood the seconds/milliseconds requirement and thought it required it in seconds.  Also the start and end are not reversed as I require the newest time at the right hand side as the new data is pushed on at this end